# openpyxl validation error schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main:color

Tags: openpyxl

I used openpyxl to create an Excel workbook.

When validating the the workbook, I get the validation error:
"The element has unexpected child element http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main:color""

The same workbook opened by Excel gives this:

```
We found a problem with some content in copy_book1_excel2019.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?
```

Steps to reproduce

(openpyxl 3.0.3,  python 3.6.9, Excel 2019 (Pro), Validation with "Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivty tool (Microsoft)

1) Create an empty  workbook in excel 2019 (Pro version) and save it as "book1_excel2019.xlsx"

2) Python  code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('./book1_excel2019.xlsx')
wb.save("copy_book1_excel2019.xlsx")
```

3) Validation:
book1_excel2019.xlsx  -> ok
copy_book1_excel2019.xlsx -> 1 validation error:
"The element has unexpected child element "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main:color"

Any hints where to look?

Comment: The validation error is incorrect: the child elements in a font tag can be in any order. The problem with the file will be due to something else.

Comment: @Charlie Clark
Thank you very much for your advice.
I looked closer into this, and found  a solution (I think)

The core.xml created by Excel:
```xml 
<cp:lastModifiedBy> dd</cp:lastModifiedBy>
```
The core.xml created by openpyxl:

```xml 
<cp:lastModifiedBy xml:space="preserve"> dd</cp:lastModifiedBy>
```
 If I  remove   `xml:space="preserve"`  Excel can open without problem.
Why does openpyxl add  xml:space="preserve" ?

Comment: I have this problem also, openpyxl is putting xml:space='preserve' into some properties of the excel sheet

Comment: It is indeed so, and its seem Excel has problem with reading such files